# How to find the next minimum value in a one-dimensional array in c#

Tags: c#

I want to find the next minimum value in a one-dimensional array so that I don't want to sort the array first.

For example if I have this array:

```
int [] a={10,5,20,3};
```

The first minimum value is 3, the second is 5, the third is 10 and the last is 20.

Now I want to know the index number of minimum values respectively. What is the index number of the first minimum value and index number of the second minimum value, and the index number of the third value ...

How can do it I in c#?

I think that by using two loops and traversing the presentation, it is possible to determine the next minimum value.

Comment: What do you understand by "next minimum value"? Please give examples of input and output.

Comment: @NineBerry I guess https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-largest-element-in-an-array/ ? (totally agree that question is quite unclear and strange - "I don't want to sort for O(n log n), but consider nested loops with O(n *n) an option"... some [edit] to clarify definitely would help)

Comment: > "`I don't want to sort the array first.`" What you are describing is **exactly** the work of sorting an array.

Comment: Any good reason to NOT have a sorted list?

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues indeed the answer should be O(n)... It is *possible* that OP actually described O(n) solution already - as long as K is known when you write code just write necessary number of loops to find corresponding element will be O(k*n) which is O(n).

Comment: Why won't you create a copy of the array and sort it ? And with each sorted element of the copy array you can get his index in the source array ?

Answer (score 1):

Using the method [Array.Sort(Array, Array)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=net-7.0#system-array-sort(system-array-system-array)) you can sort two parallel arrays by the values in the first.
To make use of this in your example, the first array (keys) would contain the values to sort upon, the second one the original indexes for the result.

```
int[] a={10,5,20,3};
int[] indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length).ToArray(); // = { 0,1,2,3 }
Array.Sort(a, indexes);
foreach (var i in indexes)
  Console.WriteLine(i);
```

If you still need the original array later, be sure to make a copy of it before calling Sort.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible with tow loop.
I don't know C# syntax but i can give you the answer in C :

```
int next_min (int* array ,int sizeofarray)
{
    int i , fmin , smin;
    fmin = array[0];
    for (i=0 , i<sizeofarray , i++)
    {
        if (array[i]<fmin)
        {
            fmin = array[i];
        }
    }

    smin = array[0];
    for (i=0 , i<sizeofarray , i++)
    {
        if (array[i]<smin && smin !=fmin)
        {
            min = array[i];
        }
    }
    return smin ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] a = { 10, 5, 20, 3 };
            int[] aCopy = new int[a.Length];
            Array.Copy(a, aCopy, a.Length);
            Array.Sort(aCopy);
            var result = string.Empty;
            foreach(int value in aCopy)
            {
                result += $"({value}, {Array.IndexOf(a, value)})\n";
            }
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
}
```

Comment: That's > O(n log n) because `IndexOf` uses a loop again.

Answer (score 0):

Use a method that gets the array and finds the minimum value in the array based on a known maximum. The call that method in a loop to get the first, second, third and so on minimum in sequence. Always use the determined minimum from the previous loop as the know maximum in the next loop.

```
internal class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds the minimum value in values that is bigger than knownMaximum
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>´Found minimum value and zero-based position</returns>
    static (int? minValue, int? position) GetNextMinimum(int[] values, int? knownMaximum)
    {
        int? minValue = null; 
        int? position = null;

        for(int i=0; i< values.Length; i++)
        {
            int value = values[i];
            
            // If the current value is bigger than knownMaximum or no know Maximum specified
            if(!knownMaximum.HasValue || value > knownMaximum.Value )
            {
                // If current value is smaller than minimum value so far
                if(!minValue.HasValue || value < minValue.Value)
                {
                    // Remember current value and position as minimum
                    minValue= value;
                    position= i;
                }
            }
        }

        return (minValue, position);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] values = { 10, 5, 20, 3 };
        int? knownMaximum = null;

        // Get 1st, 2nd and 3rd Minimum
        for (int i=1; i<=3; i++)
        {
            var (minValue, position) = GetNextMinimum(values, knownMaximum);
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}\t Position {position}\t Value {minValue}");
            
            // Use the current minValue as known Maximum for nect round
            knownMaximum = minValue;
        }
    }
}
```